# How to split strings in Tensors inside Tensorflow Datasets

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, split, tensor

I have a tf Dataset object defined as below:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((english_train, german_train))

print(train_dataset.element_spec)

Output:
(TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(14,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

The "english" and "german" objects used in the constructions are an array of strings(shape=(16000,) type=string) and an array of arrays of ints(shape=(16000, 14) type=int), respectively.

I want to split this strings in the english objects (e.g. "I am in english"  -> ["I","am", "in", "english"]). This has to be done after I constructed the Dataset.

I used the map method to try and do it:

```
string_splitter = lambda english, german : tf.strings.split(english, sep=' ')

train_dataset.map(string_splitter)

print(train_dataset.element_spec)

Output:
(TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(14,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

After I apply this operation, I inspect the dataset to see if everything went accordingly:

```
list(train_dataset.as_numpy_iterator())[0:3]

Output:
[(b"that's ludicrous .",
  array([   1,   11,    6, 5097,    3,    2,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
            0,    0,    0], dtype=int32)),
 (b'is anybody home ?',
  array([  1,   6, 366,  20,  75,   7,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
           0], dtype=int32)),
 (b"get tom's advice .",
  array([   1,  320,   52,  186,    5, 1058,    3,    2,    0,    0,    0,
            0,    0,    0], dtype=int32))]
```

As we can see, the strings were not splitted as I intended.
What can I do?

PS: the strings have variable lengths.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my mistake is that I was assuming the map method was inplace, but apparently I have to assign it (e.g. `train_dataset = train_dataset.map(string_splitter)`).

Someone, please correct me if I am mistaken.

Also, I have to fix the splitter function.